# Javafx Text clipping

Tags: javafx

I am currently using a Pane with non-managed Nodes. I place all Nodes by myself, not using any VBox or something similar.
Now I want to display texts, using the Text-Node from shapes in JavaFX. However I want to limit their size and clip off any text which is too long.

I am aware of Labels, however if possible I would like to avoid using them for this purpose.

I tried the following:

```
myPane.getChildren.add(textNode);
textNode.resizeRelocate(getX(), getY(), getW(), getH());
Rectangle clipRectangle = new Rectangle();
        textNode.setClip(clipRectangle);
        textNode.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            clipRectangle.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
            clipRectangle.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
        });
```

Notice, that the textNode is unmanaged, getting it's coordinates, width and height by some calculations I do.
My calculations of x,y,width,height seem correct.
Example values would be x=0, y=0, width=600, height=17.

It seems like I draw the clipping-rectangle in such a way, that none of the text is actually in the rectangle. Thus not showing any text.

I also tried:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(getGlobalX(), getGlobalY(), getW(), getH());
```

But to no effect.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the .clip function, maybe I am misunderstanding how I should draw the rectangle or maybe it has something to do with my Pane consisting of entirely unmanaged nodes?

I would be really thankful for any clues.

Edit:
I also tried sizing the Rectangle in the Constructor in addition to listening to the layoutBounds. Did not help.
Also notice, that getW() does not return the width of the text, but some calculated width to which I want to clip the text

Comment: AFAIK the layout bounds of a `Text` node are immediately assigned and not modified later which means your `Rectangle` probably keeps 0 as width and height. Furthermore it makes little sense to clip a non-resizable node with a `Rectangle` that is just as big as it. This way nothing will be clipped.

Comment: In fact, the getW() function returns a fixed width rather than the width of a text object. Thus if a text's width is 60, but the getW function returns 50 the text will ge clipped.
I also tried sizing the Rectangle on creation, but that did not help either.